# How to monitor the process in a container?

Tags: process, linux-kernel, cgroups, linux-containers

I currently look into the LXC container API. I am trying to figure out how can I make the operating system know to which container the currently running process belongs. In this way, OS can allocate resource for processes according to the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming your query is - Given a PID, how to find the container in which this process is running?

I will try to answer it based on my recent reading on Linux containers. Each container can be configured to start with its own user and group id mappings.

From https://linuxcontainers.org/lxc/manpages/man5/lxc.container.conf.5.html:

> **lxc.id_map**
>       Four values must be provided. First a character, either 'u', or 'g', to specify whether user or group ids are being mapped. Next is
>   the first userid as seen in the user namespace of the container. Next
>   is the userid as seen on the host. Finally, a range indicating the
>   number of consecutive ids to map.

So, you would add something like this in config file (Ex: ~/.config/lxc/default.conf):

```
lxc.id_map = u 0 100000 65536
lxc.id_map = g 0 100000 65536
```

The above basically means that uids/gids between 0 and 65536 are mapped to numbers between 100000 and 1655356. So, a uid of 0 (root) on container will be seen as 100000 on host

For Example, inside container it will look something like this:

```
root@unpriv_cont:/# ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 02:18 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/init
root       157     1  0 02:18 ?        00:00:00 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
```

But on host the same processes will look like this:

```
ps -ef | grep 100000
100000    2204  2077  0 Dec12 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/init
100000    3170  2204  0 Dec12 ?        00:00:00 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
100000    1762  2204  0 Dec12 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd --daemon
```

Thus, you can find the container of a process by looking for its UID and relating it to the mapping defined in that container's config.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I am not searching for a command line solution. I need a way for the operating system to identify which container the process belongs to.